# Find value in a dataframe based on value in another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I've to data frame, let's say A and B.

The table A is constructed like this :

```
ID a  b  c  d
1  NA NA NA NA 
2  NA NA NA NA
3  NA NA NA NA
4  NA NA NA NA
```

And the table B is constructed like this :

```
A B
a 1
a 2
a 3
b 2
b 6
b 8
b 9
c 1
c 6
c 11
d 5
d 4
```

Basically what i'd like to do is to for the ID change NA in 1 (in table A) if in the table B 1(column B) is associated with a(column A).

I'm not sure this is the best way to do this maybe using a matrix could be simpler.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please [edit] your question and show the expected result table `A`- Thank you.

Comment: How is `ID` related to `B`? As the question is currently written it is unclear what the expected result should look like. There are too many possibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* what you want to convert `B` to a dense table with `1` present if that combination is present in `B`. You can do that by recognising that `B` is the same data but with the `value` of the cells left out. We need to add that in and then `spread` to convert from long to wide:

```r
library(tidyverse)
tbl_b <- tibble(
  A = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "d", "d"),
  B = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 6, 8, 9, 1, 6, 11, 5, 4)
)

tbl_b %>%
  mutate(value = 1) %>%
  spread(A, value)
#> # A tibble: 9 x 5
#>       B     a     b     c     d
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1    NA     1    NA
#> 2     2     1     1    NA    NA
#> 3     3     1    NA    NA    NA
#> 4     4    NA    NA    NA     1
#> 5     5    NA    NA    NA     1
#> 6     6    NA     1     1    NA
#> 7     8    NA     1    NA    NA
#> 8     9    NA     1    NA    NA
#> 9    11    NA    NA     1    NA
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>